# how to create a css translateY on hover effect

Tags: css, hover, transform, mousehover

I'm looking to create a CSS hover effect that I know must be possible but I just can't work it out and was wondering if some bright spark would be able to point me in the right direction!

[See this image here showing what I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpRNM.gif)

So some text in a div above an image shows, but when you hover on the image/text div the contents move upwards in a smooth style

Would this be with a -webkit-transition translateY element?

Thanks in advance for any advice or guides that you may have!
Adam

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just for completeness and to see the two transitions methods in comparison.

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6v6c7uj8/1/) where you have two examples for this hover effect. One with `position: top` the other with `transform: translateY`

There is no real difference. The translateY seems to be smoother when repeatedly rollout/rollover (Paulie_D already mentioned the performance gain in his answer above)

Answer (score 5):

Does it *have* to be translated...no, you can do this with positioning.

Arguably, using the translation method might be better for perfomance.

```css
.one {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #663399;
  position: relative;
}
.two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  transition: top .5s ease;
  color: white
}
.one:hover .two {
  top: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat aut provident quasi veniam earum officiis vero odit doloribus blanditiis? Veritatis ab repudiandae non labore eligendi quasi officia quibusdam accusamus sit harum quisquam soluta tempore,
      odio at, iste animi numquam officiis, quam ipsa! Fuga suscipit temporibus perspiciatis explicabo ipsa laudantium aut.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will have to use the `translateY` property.

The three things you will want to remember is:

`transform: translateY();` - this is obviously for the positioning

`transition: transform 0.2s ease 0s;` - this is to smooth the movement

`overflow:hidden;` - this is to hide the bottom part when you are not hovering.

Here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bwu8ckhn/

Code:

```css
.one {
  width:300px;
  height:300px; 
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:lightblue;
}

.two {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(200px);
  transform: translateY(200px);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s ease 0s;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.one:hover .two {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

p {
  margin:0;
  padding: 1em;
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <p>
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```