# Should I use CSS or Javascript for this hover use case?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, mouseenter

I'm building a site where there is an image and icon within a container. I want to be able to hover over the container and the image would move up by 40px, icon would move right by 40px. Do I need to use Javascript in this case or is there a solution that can leverage only CSS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reason to get JavaScript involved - simply use the pseudo-selector `:hover` in CSS. Others have suggested various ways to do so in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794634/how-to-create-a-css-translatey-on-hover-effect).

If you want the image to be animated upwards, not just instantly move, you can use CSS animations as well.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons to use CSS over JS

1- CSS is easier than Javascript

2- JavaScript can be disabled

3- CSS is faster than JavaScript